# Redundant If Statement and Regex

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

The following code is clearly redundant, but in my experience I use this pattern fairly often.  Is there some better way to do this in python?

```
if re.search("at (\d{1,2}):\d{2}", p):
    a=re.search("at (\d{1,2}):\d{2}",p).group(1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is redundant; you should assign the result of `search()` to a variable instead of calling it twice:

```
m = re.search("at (\d{1,2}):\d{2}", p)

if m:
    a = m.group(1)
```

or maybe

```
a = m.group(1) if m else some_default_value
```

Also, if you're going to be using this pattern frequently, consider using [`re.compile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) to pre-compile the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Save the first search and check its boolean meaning:

```
res = re.search (...)
if res:
   a = res.group (1)
```