# Replacement for redundant regex call in Python if-else statement

Tags: python, regex

Here's a switch-by-case style code, working well as intended.

What I would like to do is:

- Sort out candidates by matching with multiple regexs AND,
- Parse its component into pieces by regex grouping.
- Regex syntax & phrases are fine as it is - so it would be best to concentrate on how to refine(or what to replace) if clause itself.

I guess it's quite inefficient to repeat calling exactly the same re.match() 2 times on every branch.

**Is there any possible replacement or a more sophisticated way in Python to "reuse" re.match object used in if statement?**

Tried to search best practices and read through the manuals as well, but it ended up with nothing.

Can't assign re.match() value or use re.compile() as suggested here because I have elif clauses:

[Redundant If Statement and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625778/redundant-if-statement-and-regex)

I can see that from Python 3.8 one can assign a variable in if statement, but I am working on Python 3.7.

[How to assign a variable in an IF condition, and then return it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550134/how-to-assign-a-variable-in-an-if-condition-and-then-return-it)

Would be appreciated if you can help.

Thanks in advance.

```
candidates = [
  'WTI CRUDE FUTURE Jul20',
  'Crude Oil Option C31',
  'O-CLK20_C43.00',
  'AMZN US 01/17/20 P1440',
  ...
]

for item in candidates:

  if re.match(r'([\w ]+) FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})', item):
     redundant_call = re.match(r'([\w ]+) FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})', item):
     Do something with .group(1), group(2) ...

  elif re.match(r'([\w ]+) Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)', item):
     redundant_call = re.match(r'([\w ]+) Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)', item):
     Do something with .group(1), group(2) ...

  elif re.match(r'O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+)', item):
     redundant_call = re.match(r'O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+)', item):
     Do something with .group(1), group(2) ...

...
```

Comment: The lack of options here is *why* 3.8 introduced the walrus operator. There is no good solution without it. Best you can do is a bunch of nested `if/else` cases, which quickly gets ugly as you have to keep indenting further and further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why the walrus operator was added; there is no good solution without it. The only way to keep short-circuiting and avoid retesting is nested `if/else` blocks, which lead to ugly "arrow pattern" code:

```
for item in candidates:
    m = re.match(r'([\w ]+) FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})', item)
    if m:
        # Do something with m.group(1), m.group(2) ...
    else:
        m = re.match(r'([\w ]+) Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)', item)
        if m:
            # Do something with .group(1), group(2) ...
        else:
            m = re.match(r'O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+)', item)
            if m:
                # Do something with .group(1), group(2) ...
```

Either do that, or upgrade to 3.8. The only simplification available is if you take the same action for any match (the groups are interchangable), in which case a single inner loop over the patterns suffices, but it doesn't look like that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your matches to a variable at the start of each iteration. Then check if the variable has stored a result for that match, then follow the same `if` structure you already have.

```
for item in candidates:
    future = re.match(r'([\w ]+) FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})', item)
    option = re.match(r'([\w ]+) Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)', item)
    other = re.match(r'O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+)', item)

    if future:
        print(future)
        # Do what you want here
    elif option:
        print(option)
        # Do what you want here
    elif other:
        print(other)
        # Do what you want here
```

This way you're only checking each match once per iteration.

Comment: Problem is, now you're unconditionally testing all three regexes even when the first or second might have been a hit already; if the first one is *likely* to hit, you're doing three times the work in that case.

Comment: Good point @ShadowRanger, crossed my mind! Would be much clearer to check in the way you have, especially over larger data sets.

Comment: Another possibility would be to combine the three regexes into one, then check which of the groups matched. If performance is important, test with both `re` and `re2` to see which is fastest.

Comment: If it comes to that, performance might be better with a combined regex than with three separate ones, so that might be a reason in itself to prefer this variant.

Answer (score 0):

A horrible (but workable) hack would be to make a helper function which takes a mutable as an argument:

```
def match(regex, item, groups):
    m = re.match(regex, item)
    if m:
        groups[:] = m.groups()  # update the groups argument in-place
    return m

def process_data(candidates): 
    groups = []
    for item in candidates:

        if match(r'([\w ]+) FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})', item, groups):
            Do something with group[0], group[1] ...

        elif match(r'([\w ]+) Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)', item, groups):
            Do something with group[0], group[1] ...

        elif match(r'O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+)', item, groups):
            Do something with group[0], group[1] ...
```

For performance, you'd compile the regexes, so the `match` function would actually use `regex.match(item)` rather than `re.match(regex, item)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option in this case would be to combine the three regular expressions into one. Depending on the data, this might even be more performant (especially with `re2`); only measurement with real data can answer that. At that point, there would only be one `.match` call and the `if`/`elif` statements would be checking which of the groups are not None.

```
for item in candidates:
  m = re.match(
    r'(([\w ]+) (FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})|Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)))|(O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+))',
    item
  )

  if m.group(3) is not None:
     Do something with .group(2), group(4) ...
  elif m.group(6) is not None:
     Do something with .group(2), group(6) ...
  elif m.group(8) is not None:
     Do something with .group(9), group(10) ...
```

As with the other solutions, you'd compile the regex for performance before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing can be reasonably done by the same code, or broken off into separate functions, we can also use a `for` loop:

```
dispatch_table = [
  (r'([\w ]+) FUTURE (\w{3})(\d{2})', handle_future),
  (r'([\w ]+) Option (P|C)([\d\.]+)', handle_option),
  (r'O-(\w{2,3})([F-Z])(\d{2})_(P|C)([\d.]+)', handle_other),
]

for item in candidates:
  for regex, handler in dispatch_table:
    m = re.match(regex, item)
    if m:
      handler(*m.groups())
      break
  else:
    raise ValueError("Unrecognised item: %s" % item)
```